# App shows meta posts in my profile's top posts

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

While viewing my own profile on the app - version 1.0.83 beta - (via my username on the side drawer), my main site's card shows my meta posts as top posts:

[image]

However, other site cards show main site posts as expected:

[image]

Other user profiles don't seem to be affected either:

[image]

It also works fine if I open my profile via another site than my main one:

[image]

More weirdness. I went to my profile (yes, I'm that narcissistic) from a Unix & Linux Meta post, and it showed Ask Ubuntu instead of U&L on top, but U&L Meta posts in the AU card:

[image]

Comment: For a moment, I could repro it on v1.0.83, but then, suddenly it's gone. Not sure what's happening there...

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I can't reproduce the first issue, but the other thing is still reproducible: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5N2Y.jpg

Comment: Yes, starting from a meta post, I can consistently repro this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TtfBb.jpg, but not from anywhere else.